# Is there a list of U.S. government regulations or actions that depend on government produced statistics?

Tags: macroeconomics, regulation, research

I'm interested in compiling a list of government actions that depend on government produced figures. For example social security benefits depend on the CPI. I don't know if such a list already exists.

Comment: That would be cool to see.